# How to deal with a lack of ability to apply ideas in math?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

I am currently studying Theoretical Computer Science, but as a Computer Science student who does not have a formal background in mathematics, past A Level (High School), I find that the ideas I learn I take for granted and do not fully understand how to apply them to each other.

For example, I attend a seminar in Homotopy Type Theory and usually someone suggests a really interesting connection between a concept in the Type theory and Set theory, Group Theory or Topology, but not having a strong knowledge of these areas I find it hard to see how people apply one concept to each other.

I get that this probably stems from a lack of experience, but when do I get to this point and what can I do to help myself get there?

Comment: This is the same as in any foreign language. If you are still not knowing enough words, its hard to enjoy the literature, and to understand how one idea can be applied to another one. So learn the words, i.e., the basic notions of group theory and algebraic topology, for example. Try to make easy examples, but with every detail.

Comment: It sounds like the only solution is to get a bit more familiar with the background concepts.  Once you have that familiarity your mind will be able to make the connections automatically.

Comment: you don't seem to have a lack of ability to apply ideas, you might have a lack of accumulated knowledge to help you come up with more and richer ideas, so keep accumulating, good luck :)

Comment: lumostar, you're talking about subjects that in all honesty seem inaccessible to some one with only an A-level background. Before you can learn about algebraic topology, which is often only learned in the fourth year or so of university, you need to learn the basics. In math, this means analysis and algebra. If you want to do this on your own, I would recommend starting with *Algebra* by Artin and *Mathematical Analysis I* and *II* by Zorich. There are alternatives if you find these too difficult.